# Evaluating security of my escape function with XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

I made a javascript function that takes an input and escapes it, returning a div string with the text as an example. Is this escape function susceptible to XSS attacks, and if so, what is the issue?

```
function escape(s) {
    s = s.toString()
    if (s.length > 100) { throw new Error("Too long!") }
    s = s.replace(/./g, function(x) {
        return { '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '&': '&amp'}[x] || x;       
    });
    if (s.match("prompt") || s.match("alert")) { throw new Error("XSS caught") }
    return "<div>"+s+"</div>"
}
```

No errors, I would just like to know if my function is vulnerable

Answer (score 1):

I can identity a few issues. There are other characters you should try to block like double quotes, single quotes, and back-ticks. Checking the string length is good practice but you can still make malicious code with shorter length. Finally, you are checking if they are using "prompt" or "alert". It is possible to obfuscate code to pass this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my understanding, since it is placed in a div element, escaping ", ' and ` is not necessary, right? If you can provide a potential bypass for it I could see what you mean and block it :)